# Could not access php session variable once the tomcat restarts

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I am developing an applicaton in java which needs to integrate some php files under tomcat server. I did everything successful, but the problem is that when i shutdown tomcat server it shows some error like

```
Exception in thread "JavaBridgeSessionTimer" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at php.java.bridge.SessionFactory$SessionTimer.run(SessionFactory.java:157)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Later if I start again I could not access any of the session variables from php files. I tried a simple php program which run within tomcat. This problem will get resolved once I restart the machine, but i don't want to do this frequently for any change in any configuration files in tomcat.

session1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<body><html>
<form action="session2.php" method="post">
         <?php $_SESSION['name']="MyName"; ?>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```

session2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php echo( $_SESSION['name'] ); ?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP session variables are held in memory. That means they are lost if you shut down the server.

If you need them to persist regardless of server restarts, you'll need to store them in a database or similar.

Comment: But I am creating the session from start once again, why it is not storing in memory as a new session variable?

Comment: You need to give more details, such as sample code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I have created a folder sess under weapp and put files below
session1.php
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="session2.php" method="post">
         <?php $_SESSION['name']="MyName"; ?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>

session2.php

<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="session3.php" method="post">
<h2><?php echo "Session =".( $_SESSION['name'] ); ?> </h2>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

session3.php

<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['name'];
?>

works fine first startup.but once restart tomcat it won't

Comment: Sorry the code is not coming properly, there are three php files above, session1.php , session2.php,session3.php Code is not showing if i post it as a new question.

Comment: Sir, I have solved the problem. There was a permission denied error in log file, when i started tomcat form root the problem get resolved.Upon restart tomcat is running from init.d means from root, that was why i could run the program. I can resolve the permission issue.